# Dynamically Selecting Signing Algorithm in OpenSSL

Tags: android, openssl, md5, sha, sign

I am creating an android app which can perform basic email security operations like encryption, decryption, signing and verification. So far I am able to perform all 4 
operations successfully. But one thing I still haven't figured out is how to specify Signing Algorithm at runtime.

I mean I want to have a drop downlist from which the user can select the signing algorithm algorithm.

I know how to do this in case of encryption. But for signing we are not specifying any algorithm in the PKCS7_Sign function call. So how do I mention which signing algorithm I should use while signing the mail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But for signing we are not specifying any algorithm in the PKCS7_sign
>   function call. So how do I mention which signing algorithm I should
>   use while signing the mail.

Try `PKCS7_add_signature`. From `<openssl dir>/crypto/pkcs7/pkcs7.h`:

```
PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO *PKCS7_add_signature(PKCS7 *p7, X509 *x509,
                                       EVP_PKEY *pkey, const EVP_MD *dgst);
```

The implementation is in `pk7_lib.c`, which can be found at `<openssl dir>/crypto/pkcs7/pk7_lib.c`. There's not much to the function. It looks like the heavy lifting is done by `PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO_set`.

Its used in a few places in the library. There is no demo in `apps/`:

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.1h
$ grep -R PKCS7_add_signature *
crypto/pkcs7/enc.c: if (PKCS7_add_signature(p7,x509,pkey,EVP_sha1()) == NULL) goto err;
crypto/pkcs7/pk7_lib.c:PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO *PKCS7_add_signature(PKCS7 *p7, X509 *x509, EVP_PKEY *pkey,
crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:       if (!(si = PKCS7_add_signature(p7,signcert,pkey, md)))
crypto/pkcs7/pkcs7.h:PKCS7_SIGNER_INFO *PKCS7_add_signature(PKCS7 *p7, X509 *x509,
crypto/pkcs7/pkcs7err.c:{ERR_FUNC(PKCS7_F_PKCS7_ADD_SIGNATURE), "PKCS7_add_signature"},
crypto/pkcs7/sign.c:    si=PKCS7_add_signature(p7,x509,pkey,EVP_sha1());
crypto/ts/ts_rsp_sign.c:        if (!(si = PKCS7_add_signature(p7, ctx->signer_cert,
```

The `openssl cms` command should allow you to work from the command line. See ["openssl smime ... [-md digest] ..." seems to be unknown option on the last version openssl](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/quot-openssl-smime-md-digest-quot-seems-to-be-unknown-option-on-tle-last-version-openssl-td22677.html). Its a bit old, but it should still hold.